# Define routes in angular based upon condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular-routing

In my app.js , i am configuring my routes to navigate to different controllers with below code

```
 var urlArray=['Suggest','Comment']; 
 var pdfURL="Suggest";
 app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
  .when('/datatrial/' +pdfURL, {
       templateUrl: 'simple/TestPanelTrial.html',
            controller: 'SimpleDemoTrailController'
        });});
```

Currently i am adding variable pdfUrl.
I want to add condition that if pdfURL matches to any of the string in urlArray ,then only use the when condition to land into respective controller.
the above code resides in app.js which is the first file to get loaded.
please inform how can this be acheived.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `.when()` you'll want a state for this, using a param.

```
.state('/datatrial', {
  url: "/datatrial/:id",
  templateUrl: 'simple/TestPanelTrial.html',
  controller: function ($stateParams) {
    if ($state.params.id !== 'Suggest') {
      $state.go('/error');
    }
  }
});
```

This is untested, but I believe it will work. Transversely, you could put that function in your controller, since I see you link to one in your question, but I put it in like I did for brevity.

Comment: Thanks for your response.my templateUrl and controller remains same irrespetive of what pdfURL gets selected.But we need to make sure that the pdfURL is the one which exist in the defined array .if it is not in that defined array, we have to show some error page.With this condition,please explain with example how to use state based routing.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some code to hep you out.